# Can anyone tell me why every time line reaches EOF, struct variable jobs[jobCount] gets filled with gibberish like "\377\377\377\377\377\377"?

Tags: c

This is the code for the function related to this problem. At first, I thought its a problem with `malloc()` or `realloc()` so I took a more static approach but it still didn't work. Running `gdb`, I found that every time the line reaches EOF, the struct variable values get replaced. Can someone please help me with this?

```
void jobFileParsing(bool verbose, char* file) {
  FILE* jobFile = fopen(file, "r");
  if (!jobFile) {
    exit_program(JOB_FILE_ERROR);
  }

  int jobCount = 0;
  char* line = read_line(jobFile);
  // JobParameters* jobs = (JobParameters*)calloc(1, sizeof(JobParameters));
  JobParameters jobs[MAX_JOBS];
  while ((line)) {
    printf("%s\n", line);
    if (line[0] == '#') {
      continue;
    } else if (!strlen(line)) {
      continue;
    }
    memset(&jobs[jobCount], 0, sizeof(JobParameters));
    jobs[jobCount] = jobLineParsing(jobCount + 1, strdup(line));
    if (jobs[jobCount].invalid) {
      continue;
    }
    jobCount++;
    if ((line = read_line(jobFile))) {
      continue;
    }
    if (verbose) {
      for (int i = 0; i < jobCount; i++) {
        verOutput(&jobs[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(jobFile);
}
```

The file contains just one line. What jobLineParsing() does is just split the line with delimiter set to ":" and fill struct variables of jobs[jobCount].

```
1:::abcd.job
```

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] and give a brief example of the input file you're using, a few lines is plenty.

Comment: This is wrong: `memset(&jobs[jobCount], 0, sizeof(JobParameters));` it should be something like `memset(jobs, 0, sizeof jobs);`

Comment: probably `read_line` is failing to check for EOF properly.  But you don't show the code.

Comment: Actually `read_line` is a given library function. I don't have access to its code.

Comment: I'm not up on the newer versions of C. `jobs[jobCount] = jobLineParsing(jobCount + 1, strdup(line));`... Is this returning an entire struct worth of data??? Is this reasonable? (Unless, of course, `JobParameters` is hiding the fact that it is a typedef pointer... Play with those and you're asking for trouble...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 passing and returning structs by value is fine as long as size is reasonable and you remember that it is shallow copy.

Comment: @stark Thanks. My heart bleeds for the stack... We'll never know about this OP... Too many mysteries, like the 'parsing' code and the value of JOB_MAX, and whether there are 8 blank lines in the input file... Mulder always said, "The answers are out there..." but, sometimes I don't think so... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3  read_line has been added as an X-file